# D3DImage flickering when resizing

Tags: c#, resize, directx, sharpdx, d3dimage

I have an issue with D3DImage when resizing.

First I had the flickering when I had a high amount of frames per second too but I could resolve it by only setting the back buffer when I am creating a new texture to render to (which I have to when resizing)

The problem is caused when I set the back buffer right after InvalidateD3DImage which of course happens in resize due to many frames send in a short time.

May SetRenderTarget method which sets the backbuffer:

```
public void SetRenderTargetDx11(Texture2D target)
        {
            if (this.mRenderTarget != null)
            {
                DisposeHelper.TryDispose(ref this.mRenderTarget);
                base.Lock();
                base.SetBackBuffer(D3DResourceType.IDirect3DSurface9, IntPtr.Zero);
                base.Unlock();
            }

            if (target == null)
                return;

            if (!IsShareable(target))
                throw new ArgumentException("Texture must be created with ResourceOptionFlags.Shared");

            var format = TranslateFormat(target);
            if (format == Format.Unknown)
                throw new ArgumentException("Texture format is not compatible with OpenSharedResource");

            var handle = GetSharedHandle(target);
            if (handle == IntPtr.Zero)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Handle");

            try
            {
                this.mRenderTarget = new Texture(mDevice, target.Description.Width, target.Description.Height, 1, Usage.RenderTarget, format, Pool.Default, ref handle);
                using (Surface surface = this.mRenderTarget.GetSurfaceLevel(0))
                {
                    base.Lock();
                    // "enableSoftwareFallback = true" makes Remote Desktop possible.
                    // See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh140978%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
                    base.SetBackBuffer(D3DResourceType.IDirect3DSurface9, surface.NativePointer, true);
                    base.Unlock();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

My Invalidate image method to draw the backbuffer to the D3DImage.

```
public void InvalidateD3DImage()
    {
            if (this.mRenderTarget != null)
            {
                base.Lock();
                base.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, base.PixelWidth, base.PixelHeight));
                base.Unlock();
            }
        }
```

Is there any way to avoid this flickering? It doesn't have any effect to the functionality but it is still not great to see.